# FlowPlayer OVA Plugin - use XML directly

Tags: javascript, flowplayer, vast, ova

So, i usually pass the url for the VAST XML into the `plugins.ova.ads.schedule[0].server.tag`.
Is there a way to pass the VAST XML string directly instead of a url for it?

```
ova: {
    url: 'flowplayer/ova.swf',
    autoPlay: true,
    "canFireEventAPICalls": true,
    debug: {
        levels: 'all, fatal, config, vast_template, vpaid, http_calls'
    },
    ads: {
        companions: {
            regions: [
                { id: "companionad300x60", "width": "300", "height": "60", "resourceType": "static" },
                { id: "companionad300x60", "width": "300", "height": "60", "resourceType": "iframe" },
                { id: "companionad728x90", "width": "728", "height": "90", "index": 0 },
                { id: "companionad728x90", "width": "728", "height": "90", "index": 1 },
                { id: "companionad300x250", "width": "300", "height": "250", "resourceType": "static" },
                { id: "companion-300x250-iframe", "width": "300", "height": "250", "index": 1 }
            ]
        },
        schedule: [
            {
                position: "pre-roll",
                server: {
                    type: "direct",
                    tag: undefined
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it's as simple as changing the type to "inject".

```
schedule: [{
   position: "pre-roll",
   server: {
      type: "inject",
         tag: xmlString
   }
}]
```